# What concerns should I have when using per-cell charging in a LiFePO4 design?

Tags: batteries, charging, lifepo4

I've started looking at using 26650 LiFePO4 cells in various (personal use) systems.  I've been learning a lot on the topic lately, including how cell balancing systems actually work.  While passively working on a design, I found myself wanting to use a per-cell charging system.  For simplicity, let us assume no limits on supply when charging.  Additionally, there will be active liquid cooling in this system, so it's reasonable to discard thermal constraints.  As such, is it a bad idea to use a per-cell, linear regulator based, charging system?  Am I wrong in thinking that this would remove the need for cell balancing during charging, since each cell would manage it's own rate of charge?

I know that this will lead to lower efficiency, given the nature of linear regulation, but for this particular design, that is of little concern.  Am I missing something obvious which would make this design dangerous / self-destructive?  My specific goal with it is to reduce the current handling requirements, as well as mitigate the need for cell balancing.  As a further detail for this thought experiment, I'm looking at putting 40+ cells in series to achieve something in the range of 120-160V nominal.  Is charging so many cells in series like this a bad idea, specifically with per-cell charging as described?

Any feedback is welcome, as long as it's not in my opamps.

Comment: "each cell would manage it's own rate of charge" How? A linear regulator alone won't manage the correct CC/CV/shutoff charging cycle for a Lithium battery. You also need each individual charging circuit to be isolated from all the others. Proper balanced charging will probably be easier.

Comment: @Finbarr "use a per-cell charging system".  The idea is that each cell would have a basic charging circuit, including thermal window check, and charge cycle management.  The other thing you mention is what I'm asking about: "each individual charging circuit...isolated from all the others".  I'm not sure what would be required in that regard.  If it's all in series then I would think that it should work, but this is where it gets to the edge of my capacity to reason about.

Comment: Maxim and OnSemi have silicon solutions to this problem. They implement charge balancing. If I had been undecided before, this would make the decision for me.

Comment: @Kartman Yes, many silicon companies do, but that presumes that balancing is a problem that needs solved.  I'm aware of an sufficiently familiar with it.  It's not something that I'm trying to avoid because I don't want to deal with it from a technical standpoint, rather, I'm exploring options for designing a system which happens to not need it.

Comment: @Finbarr If you're interested in elaborating on your comment (specifically the bit about isolation) as an answer, it would be exactly the kind of thing I'm looking to get outside perspective on.  It would (presumably) be a correct answer, and I would also be appreciative.

Comment: How were you planning to power all these separate individual cell chargers?

Comment: I tried this in a 4s 20Ah LiPO4 pack just for interest. I used a transformer with 6 identical windings. Two of them were in series and connected to a pulsed current source, my energy input. Each of the other three windings was connected via schottky diode to one cell. The cell with the lowest voltage draws the highest current because the windings are fed from the same magenetic core. The currents equalize when all cells are equally charged.